# Maximum error of number of observations within several certain intervals – Accuracy of variable is known

Tags: measurements, error-analysis

I have carried out a series of measurements of different thermal comfort parameters from which I have calculated another variable called PMV. My data set consists of hourly measurements (and calculated PMVs) for the last year. With the Root-Mean-Square Sum Method I have calculated the combined accuracy of the PMV (approximately ±8 %). And now I have to do an evaluation of the thermal environment, based on the PMV values.

The evaluation is simply done by counting the number of PMV values inside four different intervals. PMV values between -0.2 and +0.2 fall in category I, values between -0.5 and +0.5 fall in category II, values between -0.7 and +0.7 fall in category III, and values below -0.7 or above +0.7 fall in category IV.

I know that the accuracy of the individual PMV values is ±8 % as mentioned before. But, to come up with a realistic estimate of the minimum and maximum number (perhaps a 95 % confidence interval) of PMVs in the different categories I assume that it will be incorrect, to do one counting based on all PMV values *minus* 8 %, and one counting based on all PMV values *plus* 8 %, and use that at the minimum and maximum. My reason for this is that it will be very unlikely that all the PMV values are off by plus or minus 8 % at the same time.

*So, the question is: How do I take the accuracy of the variable, PMV, into account, when I want determine the maximum error (or similar) of number of PMV values in the four different categories?*

I hope it makes sense. It is not 100 % clear in my head jet either.

Comment: PMV is a non-linear function. It can be quite complicated to determine statistical error limits for these kinds of scenarios, which differ fundamentally from Gaussian distributions. Thankfully you can avoid all confusion with statistics in this case by running a Monte Carlo simulation. Make a statistical model for the distribution of your inputs, throw a million of them with a random number generator, perform the mapping to the PMV, map them to your four intervalls and count the results.

Comment: That was actually one of my thoughts. You mentioned that I could use a random number generator, and base a Monte Carlo simulation on that. My question is just if it is ok to generate the random number from a uniform distribution? Or should I generate random numbers from e.g. a normal distribution? If my individual PMV values has an accuracy of ± 8 %, is the probability of being +8 percent off equal to the probability of being e.g. -1.5 % off? No matter the answer; is there any general theory on this?

Comment: What kind of random number generator one would use depends on the problem. What are your inputs? Weather data? Set points of an AC system? I would try to make an educated guess about the distribution. For many processes it will be a normal distribution, but it really depends on what causes the deviations. Is there a general theory? Statistics is a field of its own and I am not an expert. I don't know the details of your problem, so I can't tell you if they may be a good closed form solution. When in doubt, I would always do a Monte Carlo. It gives, at least, a numerical answer.